# Choose architecture for a GitHub job runner

Tags: github-actions

I was reading [this documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/choosing-the-runner-for-a-job) on how to select the runner for a job in a GitHub workflow.

However, is there a way to select the architecture as well, such as in a strategy matrix?  My workflow builds my project and then runs tests.  I'd like it to run on `linux/i386` as well as `linux/amd64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, all the [GitHub-hosted runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners) only support `x86_64` architecture.

See [Supported runners and hardware resources](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#supported-runners-and-hardware-resources).

Even for [self-hosted runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners), only these [architectures](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners#architectures) are supported:

- `x64` - Linux, macOS, Windows.
- `ARM64` - Linux, macOS, Windows (currently in beta).
- `ARM32` - Linux.

---

`x86` binaries should run just fine on `x64` runners. However, you may use Docker images for your tests.

Comment: When using a Docker container, can I specify an `x86` image?

Comment: @DanielWalker: Yes, please take a look at [ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu) on Docker Hub. If you select a specific arch from the supported ones e.g. [i386](https://hub.docker.com/r/i386/ubuntu/), it'll take you to its page. You can pull that specific image and use it e.g. `docker pull i386/ubuntu`.